# Neo4j cypher return all nodes where property matches any array element

Tags: neo4j, cypher

This should be easy, I am overlooking something. I want to match a group of nodes and return all where the ID matches any of a group of given IDs. Something like this:

```
MATCH (b:`Band`)-[r:`something`]->(u:`SomethingElse`)
WHERE b.uuid IN ['1', '2', '3']
RETURN b
```

That returns the first node that matches. I want all that match. What am I missing?

Comment: Looks good to me (and verified in the console). Checked all the silly things?

Comment: I... swear to god, I tried it a million times with a million variations and it didn't work until now.

Comment: Note that leaving a trailing comma in the list expression leads to the somewhat unhelpful syntax error: `Invalid Input ']': expected whitespace, comment or an expression` (Encountered in Neo4j 4.1.1)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This worked. Leaving this up in case anyone else ever wants to know how to do it.